# Can we compute trend for all columns by group?

Tags: r, dataframe, trend

I have a data frame as shown below. I want to compute the trends of all numeric columns and if they are significant or not per name.

```
   library(EnvStats)
  dat=structure(list(date = c("1983-12-01", "1984-01-01", 
  "1984-02-01", 
                    "1984-03-01", "1984-04-01", "1984-05-01"), 
  rig = c(68.1, 62.4, 
                                                                       
   67.5, 78.9, 81.7, 72.2), pass = c(9.57, 10.49, 11.97, 
  11.43, 9.54, 
                                                                                                         
  8.98), name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), levels = 
  c("az",  "az", "nc", "nc", "et", "et"), class = "factor")), 
  row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Is there a function in R to do this? We can use:

```
kendallTrendTest(rig ~ date)
```

but how should I do this to have the output like this for all colums?:

```
  name    rig_trend_slope   rig_trend_pvalue pass_trend_slope   pass_trend_pvalue
  az
  nc
  et
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Quiten mentioned the number of observations in the data are limited, so a group by approach would return error.  If we want to do this on multiple columns, loop `across` the columns in `summarise`, extract the needed components from the `list` output as a tibble and then use `unnest_wider` to create wide dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(EnvStats)
library(tibble)
library(flextable)
library(officer)
dat1 <- dat %>%
  mutate(date2 = as.numeric(as.Date(date))) %>%
  # group_by(name) %>%
  # or use reframe in the devel version
  summarise(across(rig:pass, ~ 
                     {tmp <- kendallTrendTest(reformulate('date2', 
     response = cur_column()))
                     tibble(trend_slope = tmp$estimate['slope'],
                            trend_pvalue = tmp$p.value)})) %>%
  unnest_wider(where(is_tibble), names_sep = "_") %>%
  flextable %>%
  colformat_double(i=1,digit=2 )
for(nm in dat1$col_keys)
  {dat1 <- dat1 %>%
  color(i= as.formula(sprintf("~%s<0", nm)), j=nm, color="red")
  }
```

-output

[image]

To save as word format, we may use `save_as_docx` from `officer` package

```
tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".docx")
save_as_docx(
  dat1, path = tf
)
```

-output
[image]

NOTE: Here the `group_by(name)` is commented as there are only 2 observations and it returns in error for all the cases.  With the full dataset, uncomment the group_by(name)

The `broom::tidy` seems to have an issue with the class from kendallTrendTest

Comment: @bicton Try `library(tibble)`

Comment: @bicton The format for tibble seems to be having some incompatability with `flextable`.  I hope this works

Answer (score 1):

First, you only have two values per group which is not ideal. To calculate the trend per group you could use `dplyr` with `group_by` and `do` to perform the test. Also make sure your x variable in your `kendallTrendTest` is numeric. You could use `tidy` to get some coefficients. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(EnvStats)
library(broom)

models <- dat %>% 
  mutate(date2 = as.numeric(as.Date(date))) %>%
  group_by(name) %>% 
  do(model = kendallTrendTest(rig ~ date2, data = .))

models %>% 
  broom::tidy(model)
```